# Is there any library like icarousel in xamarin forms?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, icarousel

I am new to Xamarin Forms universal development platform. I need to design UI functionality same as iCarousel iOS, with the support of both iOS and Android. Any one experienced with this? Kindle share source or suggest some library(PCL) to use it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go , you can use CaurouselView by using this nuget package. 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/CarouselView.FormsPlugin/

And you can find some samples here 
https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView

Comment: Hi BraveHeart, Not looking this UI. Kindly refer the link here -
 https://ibb.co/iXNQFv

Comment: Wieth CaurouselView you can do that easily

Comment: Hi BraveHeart, Do we have any sample source for Wieth CaurouselView?

Comment: yes inside the link i sent you earlier there are some examples.